# Loop over <td> below a <th> using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with a `<th>` like this `<th class="name">` , and a list of `<td>` below that `<th class="name">`

How can I use jQuery or JavaScript to loop over all the `<td>` below that `<th class="name">`?

Comment: what do you mean by below the `th` - do you mean as an descendant element or as a sibling element or its tr

Comment: did you mean something like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/64xNq/2/

Comment: `<td>` in `<th>`.? Please show your html structure.

Comment: Can you show the HTML, from your description, it is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should have googled bit about it. you can use `.each()` with relevant selector:

```
$('th.name td').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```